# Rules to fix "LINQ expression could not be translated"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm upgrading an app to use EF Core 3.1.

I'm getting the error `The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation`.

I have about 80 queries in my code.
I understand that, for each query, I can:

- translate the query
- use `.AsEnumerable` / `.ToList` / etc. to make the query run client-side

I'd like to translate as many queries as possible.

Is there a list of rules about what can / cannot be translated? (I'm imagining a reference guide on MSDN)
Currently, my method is to change the query in various ways until it works, or I give up and add `.AsEnumerable`.
I'd like to be able to inspect a query and determine what to do, rather than having to use trial-and-error (or having to ask 80 questions on Stack Overflow!)

Comment: Show your code ? Query or linq that you are using that is not being translated ?

Comment: Just run your integration tests

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation is severely lacking in this area, and EF Core 3.1 is still quite limited in some major areas (particular group join and group by) though there are issues being worked to improve for 5.0. Your best bet is to try the queries and if they fail try looking for specific issues here or in github. LINQPad 6 is a good tool to help with this.

Comment: The most common culprits for this error is linq expressions that utilize either a custom method or library method that EF cannot translate. There are also a few uncommon Linq expression patterns that may not be implemented in EF Linq, especially with EF Core which is generally in a fair bit of flux. This can be a common issue where your domain code accepts expressions as parameters to abstract EF from calling code. This in a way violates LSP. (not in terms of an interface, but substitution, not all Linq expressions are equal) Knowledge is still needed as to what expressions are legal to EF.

Answer (score 0):

See it from the bright side! ☀

Thanks to EF Core 3.1 you've discovered 80 queries that previously was client evaluated and slow.

Tack `.AsEnumerable()` to all of them and add 80 cases to your backlog, methodically working your way from the [slowest|most accessed|biggest impact] query onwards.

As a rule of thumb, most things won't translate. Post the queries that won't translate here as separate questions and we'll be happy to help you optimize.

Happy hunting!